# CANDY chat with Openfire : receiving empty response while connecting to a autologin chat room

Tags: openfire, candy

I finally have the openfire server installed - admittedly noob to XMPP - but I'm getting there :)

I modified the .htaccess & now trying to hit the http://166.xx.xx.xx/candy-chat-candy-ca544b1/example/index.html on my server

The page shows me a "**connecting..**" message and hangs there.

Here is my setup before I delve into the firebug post/response.

I've modified the example/index.html as such :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Candy.init('http://166.xx.xx.xx:7070/http-bind/', {
        core: { debug: true },
        autojoin: ['Opentalk@conference.166.xx.xx.xx'],
        view: { language : 'en' }
    });

    Candy.Core.connect('166.xx.xx.xx', null, 'Guest'); // Connect anonymously to a specific server
});
```

In **firebug**, I see that the response is **empty**. However the post entry in firebug shows a 200 OK

And firebug complains (which I think is because the response is empty) --> "

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{80250471-6b20-4144-ad88-92777a926018} Line Number
>   1, Column 1:

**Here is the post**

```
<body rid='3954428912' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='166.xx.xx.xx' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; 
charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

Since my debug is turned on,  I see the same message as post :

```
SENT: <body rid='3954428912' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='166.xx.xx.xx' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml;
charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

**Note** : The only difference I see in my configuration is the the cross-domain part.
[The setup screenshot shown on github](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/d56d2cf045146fcd830ecd56929c658c622e068d/687474703a2f2f63616e64792d636861742e6769746875622e636f6d2f63616e64792f7075626c69632f77696b692f73637265656e73686f74732f6f70656e666972652d656e61626c652d687474702d62696e642e706e67) has this field empty, while mine has the default entry, I don't know if that is in fact a problem though.

I'm doing something wrong, but can't put a finger as to what..
Any pointers about debugging further would be great !

---

### ----------------+++++++++++--------------

Update 2/1 **
Thanks Michael, seems making the changes has taken it a step forward !!

Now I'm getting a grey page instead of hanging at "connecting..".
Seems the connection is now being established. I'm not sure if the PrivacyListError is critical (correct me).
I looked into the candy.js & seems that if the list doesn't exist it'll create one.
The next error does seem critical, since it talks about service unavailable..

**Success**

```
SENT: <body rid='2569503371' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='b967c785'><iq type='set' id='_session_auth_2' xmlns='jabber:client'><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/></iq></body> RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' type='result' id='_session_auth_2' to='b967c785@myservername.com/b967c785'/></body>  
[Connection] 
Connected [Jabber] 
Anonymous login 
[Connection] Attached
```

**Success**

```
POST http-bind/ 200 OK 101ms    

SENT: <body rid='2569503372' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='b967c785'><presence xmlns='jabber:client'/><iq type='get' xmlns='jabber:client'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:private'><storage xmlns='storage:bookmarks'/></query></iq><iq type='get' from='b967c785@myservername.com/b967c785' id='get1' xmlns='jabber:client'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'><list name='ignore'/></query></iq></body>
RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' type='result' to='b967c785@myservername.com/b967c785'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:private'><storage xmlns='storage:bookmarks'/></query></iq></body>
[Jabber] Bookmarks
```

**Error**

```
POST http-bind/ 200 OK 56ms 
SENT: <body rid='2569503373' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='b967c785'/>    
RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client'     type='error' id='get1' to='b967c785@myservername.com/b967c785'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'><list name='ignore'/></query><error code='503' type='cancel'>     <service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq></body>   
[Jabber] PrivacyListError
```

**Error - this seems more serious**

```
POST http-bind/ 200 OK 74ms 
SENT: <body rid='2569503374' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' 
sid='b967c785'><iq type='set' from='b967c785@myservername.com/b967c785' id='set1'
 xmlns='jabber:client'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'><list name='ignore'><item 
action='allow' order='0'/></list></query></iq><iq type='set' 
from='b967c785@myservername.com/b967c785' id='set2' xmlns='jabber:client'><query 
xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'><active name='ignore'/></query></iq></body>

RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' 
type='error' id='set1' to='b967c785@myservername.com/b967c785'><query 
xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'><list name='ignore'><item action='allow' order='0'/></list>
</query><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable 
xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq></body>
```

**Error - Last one, before it kinda hangs in the there**

```
POST http-bind/ 200 OK 60ms 
SENT: <body rid='2569503375' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='b967c785'/>
RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' 
type='error' id='set2' to='b967c785@myservername.com/b967c785'><query 
xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'><active name='ignore'/></query><error code='503' type='cancel'>
<service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq></body>
```

**Last ajax call fired**

```
POST http-bind/ 200 OK 60167ms  
SENT: <body rid='2569503376' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='b967c785'/>
RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
POST http-bind/
SENT: <body rid='2569503377' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='b967c785'/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your http-bind url seems to be wrong as well as the autojoin and the first param of the connect function call.

If you configured the HTTP Proxy configuration correctly, the standard [example/index.html](https://github.com/candy-chat/candy/blob/master/example/index.html) should work. 
You only need to change/add the autojoin param and change the connect function call.

Regarding the autojoin parameter: You configured a virtualhost on the XMPP server. You need to use this one as the hostname, not the IP. So it would look like `autojoin: ['Opentalk@conference.example.com']`.

The same applies to the first parameter of `connect()` you need to provide the virtual hostname of the XMPP Server.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I made the changes & seems I've got a step forward. I updated the original question with the error I got "Update 2/1". Is the PrivacyListError  show stopper ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be. Which Candy version do you use? We currently tell the people usually to use the dev version because it has some important bugfixes in it (and we couldn't release a new version yet)

Comment: oh... I used whatever was here - http://candy-chat.github.com/candy/ And it seems that is 1.09 - pretty old one. Let me try with the dev. branch now.

Comment: Did you test with the most recent release? (1.6.0) Usually a grey page is an indicator for a missing / wrong configured autojoin.